# Integration of a differential that is a function of itself.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there an explicit solution, or even a good way to numerically integrate, a relation such as:

$$\frac{dT}{dt}=-C_1T^{C_2}$$

$C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants.  $C_2$ is NOT $1$.

Comment: Do you mean $$\frac{dT}{dt} = -CT^{C_2}$$? And by explicit you mean analytical?

Answer (score 1):

Use separation of variables (all terms involving $T$ to one side of the equal sign, all terms involving $t$ on the other side):
$$
\frac{dT}{dt} = -C_1 T^{C_2} \Rightarrow
$$
Separation leads to ..

(Spoiler field follows)

> $$\int \frac{dT}{T^{C_2}} = -C_1 \int dt \Rightarrow$$

Integration gives ..

(Spoiler field follows)

> $$\frac{1}{-C_2 + 1}T^{-C_2 + 1} = -C_1 t + C$$

Comment: Ah ok.  I see now.  Thanks!!

Comment: Solving for $T$ (last step) should be easy, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

It is called the **separation of variables** technique.

$$\begin{align}
\frac {\mathrm d T}{\mathrm d t} & = -c_1 T^{c_2}
\\[2ex]
\int T^{-c_2}\operatorname d T & = -\int c_1\operatorname d t
\end{align}$$

Can you complete from here?

Comment: Sorry, you lost me.  I am an engineer, I use a lot of math, but its been 35 years since college.

Comment: @JohnMills If you do not know yet, WolframAlpha is a useful service. The queries need some fiddling sometimes, but in general it can give nice hints. [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27%28x%29+%3D+-a+y%28x%29^b+for+y) is a query for your problem.